# dplyr 0.5.0 mutate using column index

Tags: r, dplyr

I've updated dplyr (now 0.7.1) and a lot of my old code does not work because mutate_each has been deprecated. I use to do something like this (code below) with mutate_each using the column index. I'd do this on hundreds of columns. And I just can't figure out how to use the vars argument correctly with mutate_at. All examples I've seen have been using column names...which I don't want to do. I'm sure it's a simple answer but I've spent too much time trying to figure it out and would appreciate some help very much.

```
data<-data.frame(numbers=1:10, morenumbers=11:20)
change<-function(x) ifelse(x>10, 1, 2)
newdata<-data%>%mutate_each(funs(change), 1:2)
```

If I try:

```
newdata<-data%>%mutate_at(funs(change), vars(1:2))
```

Or even this:

```
newdata<-data%>%mutate_at(funs(change), vars(numbers, morenumbers))
```

I get the following error

```
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, 
not list
```

Comment: Note that strictly speaking `mutate_all` is the replacement of `mutate_each`. Also there has been a deprecation warning for a while now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new prototype of `mutate_at` is:

```
mutate_at(.tbl, .vars, .funs, ..., .cols = NULL)
```

Notice, that the `.vars` is the first argument now. So, either you specify `.vars` explicitly or change the order.

```
newdata <- data %>% mutate_at(funs(change), .vars = vars(1:2))
# OR
newdata <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(1:2), funs(change))

   numbers morenumbers
1        2           1
2        2           1
3        2           1
4        2           1
5        2           1
6        2           1
7        2           1
8        2           1
9        2           1
10       2           1
```

Comment: I new it would be some easy thing I was missing. Thank you so much. I have a deadline and was starting to panic!